# Moq setup won't work for a method call followed by an implicit conversion

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, expression-trees, implicit-conversion

For this question consider (create) the interface:

```
public interface ITestMe
{
  string TakeInt64(long x);
}
```

Then run the following code:

```
public void Test()
{
  var mock1 = new Mock<ITestMe>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  Expression<Func<ITestMe, string>> expr1 = x => x.TakeInt64(2);
  Console.WriteLine(expr1);
  mock1.Setup(expr1).Returns("OK");
  var s1 = mock1.Object.TakeInt64(2L); // OK

  var mock2 = new Mock<ITestMe>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  Expression<Func<ITestMe, string>> expr2 = x => x.TakeInt64(DateTime.Today.Year / 1000);
  Console.WriteLine(expr2);
  mock2.Setup(expr2).Returns("OK");
  var s2 = mock2.Object.TakeInt64(2L); // OK

  var mock3 = new Mock<ITestMe>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  Expression<Func<ITestMe, string>> expr3 = x => x.TakeInt64((int)(DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "Tuesday"));
  Console.WriteLine(expr3);
  mock3.Setup(expr3).Returns("OK");
  var s3 = mock3.Object.TakeInt64(2L); // OK

  var mock4 = new Mock<ITestMe>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  Expression<Func<ITestMe, string>> expr4 = x => x.TakeInt64(GetInt32());
  Console.WriteLine(expr4);
  mock4.Setup(expr4).Returns("OK");
  //var s4 = mock4.Object.TakeInt64(2L); // MockException, All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

  var mock5 = new Mock<ITestMe>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  Expression<Func<ITestMe, string>> expr5 = x => x.TakeInt64(int.Parse("2"));
  Console.WriteLine(expr5);
  mock5.Setup(expr5).Returns("OK");
  //var s5 = mock5.Object.TakeInt64(2L); // MockException, All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

  var mock6 = new Mock<ITestMe>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  Expression<Func<ITestMe, string>> expr6 = x => x.TakeInt64(GetInt32() + 0);
  Console.WriteLine(expr6);
  mock6.Setup(expr6).Returns("OK");
  var s6 = mock6.Object.TakeInt64(2L); // OK

  var mock7 = new Mock<ITestMe>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  Expression<Func<ITestMe, string>> expr7 = x => x.TakeInt64(1 * int.Parse("2"));
  Console.WriteLine(expr7);
  mock7.Setup(expr7).Returns("OK");
  var s7 = mock7.Object.TakeInt64(2L); // OK
}

static int GetInt32()
{
  return 2;
}
```

In all seven cases we make an expression tree where the `TakeInt64` gets an `int` (`Int32`) instead of a `long` (`Int64`). However, as is well known, there exists an implicit conversion from `int` to `long` which will be present in the expression tree (except in `expr1` where the compiler converts the constant for us).

How come the cases `s4` and `s5` above won't work? Curiously, as you can see, if we add `0` or multuply by `1` as in cases `s6` and `s7`, that works (even if the type is still `int`, implicitly converted to `long`)?

Please answer before year 3000 because of case `expr2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Moq. The relevant code is in [`MatcherFactory`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/MatcherFactory.cs). Specifically, the `Convert` is removed from the expression so that it can be inspected further. When the remaining topmost expression node is a method call, this node is evaluated lazily. When the remaining expression is not a method call, the whole expression (including `Convert`!) is evaluated eagerly.

This means that with lazy evaluation, the comparison is done without the `Convert` and `object.Equals(2, 2L)` is `false`. But with eager evaluation, the `Convert` is taken into account and so your code works.

I have made [an attempt at fixing this](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/pull/56), which seems to fix the issue for me.

(Whew, I almost thought I wouldn't make it in time.)

Comment: That's really cool. An answer that acknowledges I have found a bug, and a commit that fixes the issue (although I have not checked that myself).